# How to calculate position for new item inside transformed container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

I am dragging a placeholder item (relative to the window) from a sidebar and dropping it onto a pannable/zoomable "stage" which uses CSS transforms.

When dropped, it should be replaced by a new element with absolute positioning **inside the panned/zoomed "stage"** in the exact same place, visually speaking.

I am close, but the calculated position is only correct when the scale is at 1, and I can't figure out how to account for the scale programmatically.

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/a4v2guvt/

If you zoom out (mousewheel) and drag an item to the stage, it's easy to see the issue.

**Here is what I am using currently:**

```
$(theNewItem).css({
      'top': dropPosition.top + (currentY - (currentY * 2)),
      'left': dropPosition.left + (currentX - (currentX * 2))
    });`
```

**Notes on the code:**
`dropPosition` is the `$.offset()` of the dragged element (relative to the window) at the moment it is "dropped", and `currentY` and `currentX` is the transformed x,y values of the container element I am trying to add the new element to, which at `scale(1)` could be considered 0,0 relative to the window.

**Side note:** `(currentY - (currentY * 2)` is my derpy way to convert the negative number used in the transform matrix to a positive number since I don't know of any other way to convert +/- off the top of my head.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or update your question with snippet? So we can help you.

Comment: @MoshFeu added fiddle to original post. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/a4v2guvt/

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out (don't ask me how!)

Here's the solution for anyone else that may run into this:

```
'top': (dropPosition.top - containerPosition.top) / currentScale,
'left': (dropPosition.left - containerPosition.left) / currentScale
```